# node.js require relative paths

Tags: javascript, node.js, relative-path

I have node.js modules in several directories because I am following MVC pattern. I am in need to call **require** to several modules which are located outside current directory. How can I do that?

```
/app/controller/c1.js

...


/app/model/m1.js

...


/app/view/v1.js

...


/app/view/v2.js

// this works
require('./v2'); 

// these doesn't work 
require('../model/m1.js');
require('~/model/m1.js');

...
```

Why is that so?

Comment: http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.4.2/api/modules.html#modules - the documentation states it all. Basically, this is how  it is programmed. You CAN do MVC with modules separated into different folders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For modules in other directories, use the format:

```
testAuth =require('./public/javascripts/test.js'), 
//in case the test.js is in the public/javascripts directory (I am using Linux)
```

If you skip the '.js' extension, node should look for .js first before .json etc.

hope it helps.

Comment: see I have "controller" folder next to "config" folder and a file inside controller folder requires file from config folder. so what require would you let me write?

Comment: try this:  ../config/test.js // where test.js is the file name you are trying to access - let us know if it works for you (this is for Linux)

Comment: This line "require('../config/db.js');" is inside AppController module  and when AppController is required the same way from other controller, this throws Controller failed to be loaded error.

Answer (score 1):

check out this project

> https://github.com/nadav-dav/rekuire

it allows you to use "require" without the relative paths, just stating the file/class name

Comment: But the synthax is a bit cumbersome :(

var module = require('rekuire')('module')